# Mobile HTML5 Forms: Input bug

Tags: html, css

I've made an webform on my website which is responsive, and working on my OnePlus One. However, I am getting some bug reports of it because people (mostly: iPhones, Samsung Galaxy S4 or earlier versions, all on standard web browsers, even some web browsers on iOS) can't enter text in the input fields. I've got a report where the person can focus on an input box (type: email), but when he types something, it will appear as text in the URL Box of the browser. All the iPhone users just can't focus, or type text in the boxes.

Here is my HTML Form:

```
<form method='post' name='login-form'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div class="controll">
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email"  placeholder="E-Mail" required />
        </div>
        <div class="controll">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" required />
        </div>
        <div class="controll buttons">
            <div class='noacc'>Don't have an account yet? <a href='/register'>Register</a>!</div>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value="Sign in" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And some CSS (Not all, because it is spread all over the stylesheet)

```
input, select {
    color: rgba(61,60,62,1);
    font-family: 'robotoregular';
    font-size: 1.15em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,107,67,0.75);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.6em 0.6em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The email input type is fairly new and not all browsers support it.  Mobile devices are especially precarious to code for considering you really don't know what browser(s) people are using on their mobile devices.  In most cases the built-in browser on devices will read the email input type properly, but on some older devices, html5 does not work right unless they have downloaded and installed a browser such as Google Chrome.

I would suggest using an input type of "text" and use some javascript or jquery to validate the email address before submitting.

Comment: Even the text as type doesn't work. First step of debugging ;p